# Breaking in std::for_each loop

Tags: c++, stl

While using std::for_each algorithm how do I break when a certain condition is satisfied?

Comment: I personally don't like exiting early from for loop. IMO, for loop has to be used only when you need to iterate fully. If you want to break in between,consider other looping constructs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm, which will stop and return the iterator to the first element where the predicate condition applied to returns `true`. So your predicate should be changed to return a boolean as the continue/break condition.

However, this is a hack, so you can use the algorithms.

Another way is to use BOOST_FOREACH.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but what if I want to apply some operations to the elements in the loop until the condition is satisfied?

Comment: Naveen, what's with that? you can do any operation on the elements whatsoever. then at any time you can "break;" and the loop exits.

Comment: find_if accepts input iterators, not output iterators. Then, I would recommend to implement the loop by hand, or use BOOST_FOREACH.

Comment: why not use find_if only? I don't see anything forbidding the function object to modify the passed item. It seems just like for_each. So if the iterator returns a T& from its *it (like vector<int>::iterator), i don't think it's wrong to modify the item then. i won't say i'm 100% sure, but i'm pretty sure about that.

Comment: the fact that it takes InputIterator's is a lower bound. it doesn't mean that it can't take forward iterators, for example. But it means the algorithm itself won't require forward iterator capabilities. The passed function object, of course, may do that. It's then a concern of the user of find_if. But i will agree with you - it looks a bit hacky

Comment: @litb: I agree with you regarding the required features of find_if. This is a reason for considering using find_if in this context as a hack. Normally, you expect find_if not to change the objects in the sequence, yet... using it in this context will do so (hidden side effects).

Comment: For the predicate parameter p: "The expression p(v) must be convertible to bool for every argument v of type (possibly const) VT, where VT is the value type of InputIt, regardless of value category, and *must not modify v*". From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 33):

You can use std::any_of (or std::all_of or std::none_of) e.g. like this:

```
std::vector<int> a;
// ...     
std::all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](int val) { 
  // return false if you want to break, true otherwise
  });
```

However, this is a wasteful solution (return values are not really used for anything), and you're better off writing you own loop.

Comment: The best answer that really helped

Comment: Nice - a pity the predicate can't modify its argument (so no `[&](int& val) { val++; return true; }`).

Comment: This answer does not work since C++17, because the return value of `std::all_of()` is a `[[nodiscard]]`.

Answer (score 17):

You can break from the for_each() by throwing an exception from your functor.  This is often not a good idea however, and there are alternatives.

You can retain state in your functor.  If you detect the 'break' condition, simply set a flag in your functor and then for each subsequent iteration simply return without doing your functor's thing.  Obviously this won't stop the iteration, which might be expensive for large collections, but it will at least stop the work from being performed.

If your collection is sorted, you can find() the element that you want to break at, then do for_each from begin() to the element find() returned.

Finally, you can implement a `for_each_if()`.  This will again not stop the iteration but will not evaluate your functor which does the work if the predicate evaluates to false.  Here are 2 flavors of `for_each_xxx()`, one which takes a value and performs the work if operator==() evaluates to true, and another which takes two functors; one which performs a comparison ala find_if(), and the other which performs the work if the comparison operator evaluates to true.

```
/* ---

    For each
    25.1.1

        template< class InputIterator, class Function, class T>
            Function for_each_equal(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value, Function f)

        template< class InputIterator, class Function, class Predicate >
            Function for_each_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred, Function f)

    Requires:   

        T is of type EqualityComparable (20.1.1) 

    Effects:    

         Applies f to each dereferenced iterator i in the range [first, last) where one of the following conditions hold:

            1:  *i == value
            2:  pred(*i) != false

    Returns:    

        f

    Complexity: 

        At most last - first applications of f

    --- */

    template< class InputIterator, class Function, class Predicate >
    Function for_each_if(InputIterator first, 
                         InputIterator last, 
                         Predicate pred, 
                         Function f)
    {
        for( ; first != last; ++first)
        {
            if( pred(*first) )
                f(*first);
        }
        return f;
    };

    template< class InputIterator, class Function, class T>
    Function for_each_equal(InputIterator first, 
                            InputIterator last, 
                            const T& value, 
                            Function f)
    {
        for( ; first != last; ++first)
        {
            if( *first == value )
                f(*first);
        }
        return f;
    };
```

Comment: You can break by throwing an exception. But the find() solution is better in some cases at least

Comment: I upvoted this answer after just reading the code, but I must say that throwing an exception just to break a loop early is never a good idea, unless you actually need to throw if condition holds.

Comment: Throwing exceptions are expensive to unwind since most compiler can't optimize this code. and should only be used when there is a real problem like am OS resource you need is down.

Answer (score 8):

If you want do some actions while condition is not satisfied, maybe you need change algorithm on something like `std::find_if`?

Comment: This is the easy way. Just return true when you want to stop.

Comment: As of C++17 his does not work, 
because the return value of `std::find_if()` is a `[[nodiscard]]`. 
Any alternatives ?

Answer (score 7):

As already shown by others it is only achievable with workarounds that IMHO obfuscate the code.

So my suggestions is to change the for_each into a regular for loop. This will make it more visible to others that you are using break (and maybe even continue).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it, unless you throw an exception, which is not a good idea because you don't do flow control with exceptions.

Update: apparently Boost has a for_each_if that *might* help, but you're not using Boost.

Comment: you dont need boost to use a for_each_if().  It is simple to implement.

Comment: Right, but the question is not "how do I implement for_each_if()".

Comment: for_each_if doesn't solve the question either. It was not "how do I make my code do nothing on the elements after a certain point", but "how do I stop the iteration entirely". There can be some serious performance costs to traversing the entire range if the iteration could have been terminated earlier. So the answer is exceptions or nothing. (where nothing means "redesign so you don't have to break, or don't use for_each for this".)

Comment: Never said it did help. Perhaps time for for_each_while? (or for_each_until?) I'm sure there's something that can be implemented that would solve the problem. The issue there is: at which point in time does it become more work to implement that "generic" solution instead of just using a for(;;) loop and break.

Answer (score 1):

You throw an exception.  Whether or not it's a good idea is sort of a style question, pace @Dan, but may be more of an issue with your design.  for_each is intended for a sort of functional-programming style, which implicitly assumes that your function can be applied uniformly across the set.  So, if you *do* need to break, that could be consiered an unusual condition, and therefore worthy of an exception.

The other solution, and a more "functional" solution, is to write your function so that if it shouldn't have an effect on some applications, then write it to have no effect.  So, for example, if you had a summing function, have it add 0 in the cases you would have "broken" from.

Comment: Throwing exceptions for flow control is not a matter of style. It's a matter of taste. Bad taste, that is.

Comment: Sounds like it's a matter of blind zealotry more than taste. It does the job, simpler, cleaner and more elegantly than most of the other solutions. I kinda agree with Charlie on this. If you *do* need to break from a for_each, then 1) there's probably an underlying design issue, and 2) throwing an exception is the simplest solution.
As long as the exception can be so cleanly isolated (it's one single line of code you need to wrap in try/catch), using it for flow control is tolerable.

Comment: It's kind of like the old anti-goto zealotry.  Yes, gotos can be harmful, but sometimes in some languages they're the best of the available options.

Comment: Oh, so now knowing the difference between flow control and exceptions is called "zealotry".

Comment: Really depends why you are breaking. If there is an "exceptional" reason for that, sure - throw an exception. However, if it is a "normal" thing I would be *very* careful with exceptions - they may kill the performance and make the code hard to debug.

Comment: I don't want to get in to a Holy War regarding the "correct" use of exceptions, but it isn't accurate to say that throwing exceptions is a matter of style.  Whether or not throwing exceptions is a good idea depends on the structure of your program, and the decision to throw or not to throw is much more substantial than simply deciding where to put your curly braces.

Comment: I love you guys/girls. I'm not sure my opinion matters much, but if I came across an exception handler in this circumstance, my first thought "can I be certain of data integrity?" say the for_each was modifying elements: What state is the data in? Can this be recovered from?

Comment: Get a *grip* people. Dave is saying "it's not a matter of style its a matter of taste" as if that actually, you know, has technical meaning.  LOOK AT WHAT I WROTE: "how do you do it?  Throw an exception.  Is that good?  Maybe not.  There's another way, that fits the functional paradigm better."  What you're bitching about is that I wasn't *sufficiently* obnoxious about it.  Oh, and Dave, re: knowing the difference?  Keep a civil tongue in your head.

Comment: Who deleted the comments on this answer made yesterday? I for example linked to another answer of this guy, but the comment doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: Pretty well has to be an admin, doesn't it?  I certainly don't have a delete handle on any comments but my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::find_if` instead `std::for_each`:

```
int aaa[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
std::find_if(aaa, std::next(aaa, sizeof(aaa) / sizeof(int)), [](const auto &i) {
    if (i == 5)
        return true;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return false;
});
```

Output:
1
2
3
4

Comment: How does this add anything to some of the other answers (notably, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760234/10871073))?