# How do I stop the iteration a for_each() loop? for(:) is not a viable option

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010

I like the `for_each()` syntax, but escaping from one when a condition is met is not possible (I could throw an exception, but that seems a bit overkill).

I've used `find_if()` to do it, but I've had a manager feel that using it in this way is a bit obscure.

I'm using MSVS2010 so `for(:)` isn't available.

Is my only option to do a `for(auto i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i)`?

Comment: Doesn't break; can do it?

Comment: No, break only works in loop structures.

Comment: `find_if` doesn't seem that obscure, depending on how well the functor is named and commented.

Comment: God forbid you have to write an actual for loop

Comment: I was using a lambda.

Comment: lambda or functor, it is still relevant how clear the meaning is (comments, names of variables, etc).

Comment: Exceptions don't have to be overkill, but I don't know any compiler that went to the trouble of optimizing them :-(

Comment: That was my opinion.  But I'd need to have a source stating that using `find_if` this way is the way to go I think.

Comment: @MarcGlisse exceptions are not about overkill or not overkill, they are about detecting exceptional situations (situations that should not occur in normal running but can), so we know nothing about his problem we can't tell which is correct

Comment: I'd say that exiting the loop before iterating over all the elements is overkill as it is more a code flow thing, not a particularly exceptional event. I.e. it is just an event that is as likely to occur as not.

Comment: I removed the C++11 tag and added the C++ tag.  You should get more eyes, for one, and for two, the only part of C++11 that is mentioned you're unable to actually use.  So...

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I think it's best to leave both in, since he is technically using c++11 features and shouldn't restrict himself, if a c++11 feature that msvc has is useful people should feel free to use it

Comment: The loop structure is used in a load/save context so it would be exceptional, however, the code that is already there is using return values to determine if there was an error reading/writing.  So, I'm also hesitant with changing this paradigm.

Comment: @aaronman, that's cool too.  The C++ tag doesn't necessarily mean "don't use C++11", but I get you. :)

Comment: This is actually a decent question.

Comment: @Adrian checkout the new answer I posted, I is basically BOOST_FOREACH written in 20 loc

Comment: @aaronman Exceptions are a language feature, how you use them is your business. If you want to use them only for errors, that's your choice. Exceptions allow for a different control flow (kind of like goto, break, continue, but into the caller) that can be very useful for regular code. This prejudice against exceptions and the fact they are implemented to be slow as hell form a vicious circle. Now I agree that knowing more about the specific problem would help judge if exceptions are a good idea.

Comment: @MarcGlisse there is no prejudice against exceptions, they affect control flow but they are a tool for basic control flow. Part of the beauty of exceptions is that they have no cost if they are not thrown, which is the reason they are costly when they are thrown. in C before exceptions return value error handling was used, c++'s model is faster if used properly because there is 0 cost for not throwing. There are plenty of other features for control flow in c++ don't use exceptions for anything that doesn't need them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking in std::for\_each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760221/breaking-in-stdfor-each-loop)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [`BOOST_FOREACH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/foreach.html),  which is just a header BTW so you won't even have to build and link to boost.

```
#include <string>                                                                  
#include <iostream>                                                                
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>                                                       

int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    std::string hello( "Hello, world!" );                                          

    BOOST_FOREACH( char ch, hello )                                                
    {                                                                              
        std::cout << ch;                                                           
        if(ch == 'o')break;                                                        
    }                                                                              

    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

If boost is not an option, just use a normal for loop like you said

```
for(auto i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i)
```

It's not a big deal :), or you could upgrade your compiler. There is no way for us to tell if `find_if` is obscure or not without seeing the problem at hand and your code.

Here is my version of for_each, don't trust it 100% boost's is quite long and I'm sure mine has subtle differences since it is so short (also leaks a name into your space, IDT boost's does that) **This one is my third shot at doing this, pretty sure it's totally correct other than the leaked variable name `obscure_variable_name`.**

```
#include <string>                                                                  
#include <iostream>                                                                
#include <iterator>                                                                
#define AARON_FOREACH(var,container)   \                                           
    if(int obscure_variable_name = 0) {} else \                                    
    for(auto var = *std::begin(container);obscure_variable_name+1;obscure_variable_name=-1) \
    for(auto iter = std::begin(container); \                                       
        iter != std::end(container)?( var = *iter), true : false ; ++iter)         

int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    std::string hello( "Hello, world!" );                                          
    AARON_FOREACH(ch,hello)                                                        
    {                                                                              
        std::cout << ch;                                              
    }                                                                              
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    AARON_FOREACH(ch,hello)                                                        
    {                                                                              
        std::cout << ch;                                              
        if(ch == 'o')break;                                                        
    }                                                                              

    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

Comment: No, I don't think that I'll bring in Boost just for that.  I think it's not worth it.  And we will be upgrading our compiler, but that won't be till we get MSVS2013 and then there's the migration time... yada yada yada.  I'm guessing it'll be sometime mid next year at least.  But looks like your the winner, as you more or less stated, no, it can't be done. :)  I'll just wait a day just in case.

Comment: @Adrian hey just wanted to make sure you noticed that I posted a more acceptable solution to your problem

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::find_if` is the better way to go. As Scott Meyers said in his *Effective STL* book:

> Guideline: Prefer algorithm calls to explicit loops. Algorithm calls are often clearer and reduce complexity. If no suitable algorithm exists, why not write it? You’ll use it again.

Using `std::find_if` with `std::for_each` is much cleaner, since it separates out the logic to select what items to process, and the logic to process the items. This also can help improve testability.

Futhermore, `std::find_if` and `std::for_each` can be combined together to create a new algorithm such as `for_each_until`, like this:

```
template <class Iterator, class F, class Cond> 
void for_each_until(Iterator b, Iterator e, F f, Cond cond) 
{ 
    auto stop = std::find_if(b, e, cond);
    std::for_each(b, stop, f);
}
```

Which you can reuse again.

Comment: @Jarod42 `find_if` wouldn't modify the container, `for_each` would. Also, writing `for_each_until` is a good idea, I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: That's interesting, but wouldn't this increase the execution time by a factor of 2?  Or are the compilers getting so smart that they will bring these two loops together?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd start by writing a small algorithm for this general purpose:

```
template <class Iter, class F, class Cond> 
void for_each_until(Iter b, Iter e, F f, Cond cond) { 
    for( ; b != e; ++b) {
        if (cond(*b))
            return;
        f(*b);
    }
}
```

With that, the task becomes fairly trivial. For example, to execute `f` an all the `int`s in a collection `c`, breaking when/if we get to a negative number, we'd use code something like this:

```
for_each_until(c.begin(), c.end(), f, [](int i) { return i < 0; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `std::for_each`, how about using a range-based for loop?

```
for (const auto& item : container)
{
    if (!condition_met) { continue; }

    // process item
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I've never heard of it being referred to as `for(:)`.  I wasn't sure what that part of your question meant.. Pretty quick to downvote for someone trying to help you.

Comment: Np.  I've seen it referred that way here on SO before.

Comment: Don't take it so personally @zmb, downvotes for not reading the question is common here.  I've had gotten it done to me myself.

Comment: The SO system said not to use the c++0x tag, so I didn't.

Comment: Is that the compiler version?  What MSVS is that?  2012?

Comment: Also, this would be more efficient if you used `for (const auto& item: container) { if (condition_met) { break; } /* process item */ }` as I was asking how to leave the loop.

Comment: @aaronman: You are not given the right to vote in order to remove other people's right to vote. Vote up if you think the answer is "great", not to "counteract" anyone else's viewpoint. And nobody has suggested deleting it. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mentioned at the end I think that for anyone who has full c++11 support this is the correct answer

Comment: @aaronman: So what? Voting only to "counteract" someone else's vote is offensive. If you're upvoting because the answer deserves it then fine, but you stated otherwise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess it's both but I'll remove the comment, and this one after you see it

Answer (score 0):

Create a functor that tracks whether the condition for break is reached, and return immediately if it is.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct addOneUntilFive {
  void operator() (int& i) {
    if (breakReached)
      return;
    if (i == 5) {
      breakReached = true;
    }
    i += 1;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }

  bool breakReached;
} instance;

int main() {
  std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  std::for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), instance);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like my use of `find_if()`

Comment: Oh, so you are still iterating over the objects that are not useful.  Hmmmmm.  Interesting, but a bit wasteful.

Comment: Well, if you can use `find_if()` that's a better solution.  Because it allows you to break the loop completely.  But sometimes your break condition can rely on many other factors, and `find_if` may not be appropriate.  Honestly though.  The REAL answer is to just write a normal for loop.

Comment: Also you discussed using an exception.  Don't do that.  That's 100x more wasteful than this method.

Comment: I think that using an exception is also too much.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: what makes you say that throwing an exception is 100 times more wasteful than continuing to iterate over the rest of a collection doing nothing? If the collection had 10000 elements instead of 10, does that mean the exception is 10 times less wasteful? I agree of course that the right thing to do is to write a loop -- and hide it in a user-defined algorithm if it makes you feel better :-)

Comment: It does depend on the use case.  100x is an off the cuff estimate, so I tested it out.  At `O3` it runs 66.818x slower with the throw, so an exception is worth around 267 runs around the loop.  If you expect to have less than 267 skipped elements, it's faster to not throw.  I tried to measure against a standard for loop, but my dummy loop was completely optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the answers, no you can't break out of a `std::for_each` run without:

- throwing an exception (hackery!)
- not using `std::for_each` in the first place.

i.e. **you were right**. Yes, use a proper loop.