# I want to print the most visited sites/urls in the browser

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

Below is the code that I have written in C++ and it is printing the wrong result for the 2nd and 3rd output line. I am not able to figure it out why it is happening.

Below is the code  which I have written and it is a completely functional code on visual studio. This code expects the one input file named urlMgr.txt whose content should be URLs. Below is the sample URLs which I am using it.

```
  web.whatsapp.com 
  web.whatsapp.com 
  cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if 
  stackoverflow.com/questions/760221/breaking-in-stdfor-each-loop 
  mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085331/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c14
  mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox 
  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda 
  https://www.google.co.in/?ion=1&espv=2#q=invariant%20meaning
  mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699083/where-can-i-find-all-the-exception-guarantees-for-the-standard-containers-and-al
  https://www.google.co.in/?ion=1&espv=2#q=array+of+references:quora&start=10
  mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox 
  web.whatsapp.com 
  quora.com/Whats-the-purpose-of-load-factor-in-hash-tables 
  https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-the-rehash-and-reserve- methods-of-the-C++-unordered_map      cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/load_factor
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor 
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor 
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor 
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor 
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor 
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor 
  cplusplus.com/max_load_factor
```

Code is also pasted below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class urlInfo
{
public:
    urlInfo(string &url):urlName(url),hitCount(1)
    {
    }

    int getHitCount() const
    {
        return hitCount;
    }

    string getURL()
    {
        return urlName;
    }

    string getURL() const
    {
        return urlName;
    }

    void updateHitCount()
    {
        hitCount++;
    }

    void setHitCount(int count)
    {
        hitCount = count;
    }

private:
    string urlName;
    int hitCount;
};

class urlInfoMaxHeap
{
public:
    bool operator() (urlInfo *url1, urlInfo *url2) const
    {
        if(url2->getHitCount() > url1->getHitCount())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};


bool operator==(const urlInfo &ui1,const urlInfo& ui2)
{
    //return (ui1.getURL().compare(ui2.getURL()) == 0) ? 1:0;

    return (ui1.getURL() == ui2.getURL());
}

namespace std
{
    template <> struct hash<urlInfo>
    {
        size_t operator()(urlInfo const & ui)
        {
            return hash<string>()(ui.getURL());
        }
    };
}

class urlMgr
{
public:
    urlMgr(string &fileName)
    {
        ifstream rdStr;
        string str;
        rdStr.open(fileName.c_str(),ios::in);
        if(rdStr.is_open())
        {
            int len;
            rdStr.seekg(0,ios::end);
            len = rdStr.tellg();
            rdStr.seekg(0,ios::beg);
            str.reserve(len+1);
            char *buff = new char[len +1];
            memset(buff,0,len+1);
            rdStr.read(buff,len);
            rdStr.close();
            str.assign(buff);
            delete [] buff;
        }
        stringstream ss(str);
        string token;

        while(getline(ss,token,'\n'))
        {
            //cout<<endl<<token;
            addUrl(token);
        }

    }


    void addUrl(string &url)
    {
        unordered_map<string,urlInfo*>::iterator itr;
        itr = urls.find(url);
        if(itr == urls.end())
        {
            urlInfo *u = new urlInfo(url);
            urls[url] = u;
            maxHeap.push_back(u);
        }
        else
        {
            itr->second->updateHitCount();
            urlInfo* u = itr->second;
            vector<urlInfo*>::iterator vItr;
            vItr = find(maxHeap.begin(),maxHeap.end(),u);
            if(vItr!=maxHeap.end())
            {
                maxHeap.erase(vItr);
                maxHeap.push_back(u);
            }
        }

        make_heap(maxHeap.begin(),maxHeap.end(),urlInfoMaxHeap());
    }

    void releaseResources()
    {
        for_each(urls.begin(),urls.end(),[](pair<string,urlInfo*> p){
            urlInfo* u = p.second;
            delete u;
        });
    }

    void printHeap()
    {
        for_each(maxHeap.begin(),maxHeap.end(),[](urlInfo* u){
            cout<<endl<<u->getHitCount()<<"  "<<u->getURL();
        });
    }
private:
    unordered_map<string,urlInfo*> urls;
    vector<urlInfo*> maxHeap;
};


int main()
{
    string fileName("urlMgr.txt");
    urlMgr um(fileName);
    um.printHeap();
    um.releaseResources();
    cout<<endl<<"Successfully inserted the data"<<endl;
}
```

The output i am getting is

```
   8 cplusplus.com/max_load_factor
   3 web.whatsapp.com
   4 mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
   1 en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
   1 other url's and so on. //all other url's show count as 1.
```

What i expect is

```
   8 cplusplus.com/max_load_factor   
   4 mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
   3 web.whatsapp.com
   1 en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
   1 other url's and so on. //all other url's show count as 1.
```

Comment: use the below pasted URLs in the urlMgr.txt  file:- 
https://web.whatsapp.com/
https://web.whatsapp.com/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760221/breaking-in-stdfor-each-loop
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085331/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c14
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=invariant%20meaning
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699083/where-can-i-find-all-the-exception-guarantees-for-the-standard-containers-and-al
https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=array+of+references:quora&start=10
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
https://web.whatsapp.com/
https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-purpose-of-load-factor-in-hash-tables
https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-the-rehash-and-reserve-methods-of-the-C++-unordered_map
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/load_factor/

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/

Comment: Use all the above url in the input file and each URL must be in a separate line. Press enter after every line (i.e \n should be there)

Comment: You should put your comments in your question as a test input.

Comment: I didnt find the 2nd and 3rd output line and to be honest I am too lazy to search for it. Anyhow you missed to say what output you expect to get and what is wrong with the output you get.

Comment: afaik adding stuff to `namespace std` is forbidden by the standard and causes undefined behavior

Comment: @tobi303 In certain cases it is allowed.  specializing `std::hash` is on of those cases: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8157967/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver whenever I think I understood something there is some exception. Learning C++ never stops being fun ;). Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @tobi303 No problem.  I have been using it for years and I learn something new/different way to accomplish a task almost daily on this site.

Comment: @KapilSatija I am getting this output.Please tell what were you expecting.http://imgur.com/rndKOTr

Comment: It was not allowing to enter the URL that's why I have added it separately in the comments.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal:- Your output is differing slightly I think your input file has got some discripency. In my case the first URL in the input has the hit count of 8 and 3 URL has the hitcount of value 4. Although I am creating the max heap based upon the hitcount on every insertion but still the URL whose hitcount is 4 is placed at 3rd position instead of second one.That's my problem.I want to know what mistake I am doing which is resulting in this problem.

Comment: @tobi : Thanks for sharing the information.I will also add the output file the better understanding of problem.

Comment: I am pasting the output of my screen as I am not getting any option of uploading the snapshot.                              OUTPUT SAMPLE:-   
8  http://www.cplusplus.com/max_load_factor/
3  https://web.whatsapp.com/
4  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
1  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
1  https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#
q=invariant%20meaning
1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699083/where-can-i-find-all-the-exceptio
n-guarantees-for-the-standard-containers-and-al
1  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

Comment: @KapilSatija .Yes .I guess there were some extra spaces at the end of some url's and were being treated separately.

Comment: @KapilSatija I have edited the question for you.Please see if this is your actual problem.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal:- Thanks a lot Gaurav. You have understood my problem now. I am expecting that it will be sorted because on each insertion of the element I am applying make_heap . Have you identified the reason also for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some debugging i have found the problem.The problem is in the way you are interpreting how `max_heap()` works.

Consider this.

```
url1 occurs 8 times
url2 occurs 4 times
url3 occurs 3 times
```

After a call to `max_heap()` what you will get is

```
maxHeap[0]=8                     8
maxHeap[1]=4                   4   3
maxHeap[2]=3
```

Or you can also get

```
maxHeap[0]=8                     8
maxHeap[1]=3                  3     4
maxHeap[2]=4
```

Both of the above are maxHeaps but you are considering that only the first heap can occur and so in the below code you are just printing `maxHeap` content without realizing that you may be printing second heap.

```
  void printHeap()
{
    for_each(maxHeap.begin(),maxHeap.end(),[](urlInfo* u){
        cout<<endl<<u->getHitCount()<<"  "<<u->getURL();
    });
}
```

To resolve this.One way is to after picking up `maxHeap[0]` .You delete first element and again call max_heap before picking up `maxHeap[0]` again.Or you can also have something like below.

```
 while(maxHeap.size()>0){
    cout<<(*maxHeap.begin())->getHitCount()<<" "<<(*maxHeap.begin())->getURL()<<endl;
    std::pop_heap(maxHeap.begin(),maxHeap.end(),urlInfoMaxHeap());maxHeap.pop_back();}
```

In the above code [pop_heap()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/pop_heap/) will move the topmost element(which has the highest priority according to your implementation of compare function which you pass to `make_heap()`) to the end and heapify again. You can then delete the last element then.

Also i did not find the use of the below in your code

```
 vector<urlInfo*>::iterator vItr;
        vItr = find(maxHeap.begin(),maxHeap.end(),u);
        if(vItr!=maxHeap.end())
        {
            maxHeap.erase(vItr);
            maxHeap.push_back(u);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I was also thinking the same but was not sure before your explanation.Two Reason why I have added the code for erasing and again inserting. I am thinking. 1) max_heap will not update the heap since no insertion has happened int the container if i remove the code snippet you have pointed(so forced the insertion after deletion). 2) I was also not sure whether automatic heapify will happen after the updation of hitcount (without the call to max_heap in the end).

Comment: You might want to have a look at `push_heap`   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/                                  and if the solution worked for you, you could accept this as an answer.

Comment: If on updating the hitcount automatic heapify can work then I can directly switch to the priority_queue if there is any way by which either I can retrigger heapify on the priority_queue container. Any idea about this?

Comment: @KapilSatija AFAIK updating a member of priority_queue will not update its ordering until you remove that element and insert it again.Also you cannot update any member of priority_queue you want.I don't see `priority_queue` working here

Comment: @KapilSatija Think about this how will you check whether a member exists in priority queue or not.

Comment: :- That was the reason I did not used the priority queue here. Earlier I was trying to use that but could not able to use it because of the challenge that you mentioned. Thanks a lot for clarifying all my doubts.

Comment: @KapilSatija Your welcome.If this answer helped you, please accept this as answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow